# Python confusion -- convention, name and value

Tags: python

I am a beginner and have a confusion when I am learning python. If I have the following python code:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([1,0,0])
Y = X
X[0] = 2
print Y
```

Y will be shown to be `array([2, 0, 0])`

However, if I do the following:

```
import numpy as np
X = np.array([1,0,0])
Y = X
X = 2*X
print Y
```

`Y` is still `array([1,0,0])`

What is going on?

Comment: Here you modify *the local variable `X`* the change will not be reflected to `Y` since `Y` is not even aware `X` exists.

Comment: Thanks, sorry I was not clear in the post. I change the line X[0] = 2 to X = 2*X in the original code above.

Comment: Because assignment to a slice/indexing operation *mutates the data structure*, where as using the `*` operator generates a *new* data structure. Also, read and understand this: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Thanks @juanpa.arrivillaga The document is very useful

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `X` and `Y` are **references** to the same object `np.array([1,0,0])` this means that regardless whether a call is done *through* `X` or `Y`, the result will be the same, but *changing* the reference of one, has no effect.

If you write:

```
X = np.array([1,0,0])
Y = X
```

basically what happens is that there are two *local variables* `X` and `Y` that **refer** to the same object. So the memory looks like:

```
     +--------+
Y -> |np.array| <- X
     +--------+
     |[1,0,0] |
     +--------+
```

Now if you do `X[0] = 2` that is basically short for:

```
X.__setitem__(0,2)
```

so **you call a method on the object**. So now the memory looks like:

```
     +--------+
Y -> |np.array| <- X
     +--------+
     |[2,0,0] |
     +--------+
```

If you however write:

```
X = 2*X
```

first `2*X` is *evaluated*. Now `2*X` is short for:

```
X.__rmul__(2)
```

(Python first looks if `2` supports `__mul__` for `X`, but since `2` will raise a `NotImplementedException`), Python will fallback to `X.__rmul__`). Now `X.__rmul__` **does not change `X`: it leaves `X` intact**, but constructs a **new array** and returns that. `X` catches by that new array that now references to that array).

which creates an new `array` object: `array([4, 0, 0])` and then `X` **references to that new object**. So now the memory looks like:

```
     +--------+         +--------+
Y -> |np.array|     X ->|np.array|
     +--------+         +--------+
     |[2,0,0] |         |[4,0,0] |
     +--------+         +--------+
```

But as you can see, `Y` still **references to the old object**.

Comment: `__setitem__` is missing some underscores

Comment: Also, `__mul__` is a method just like `__setitem__`, so you are not really explaining why the multiplication does not propagate to `Y`.

Comment: No it calls `__rmul__` :)

Answer (score 8):

think of it this way: 
the equals sign in python assigns references.

`Y = X` makes Y point to the same address X points to

`X[0] = 2` makes x[0] point to 2

`X = 2*X` makes X point to a new thing, but Y is still pointing to the address of the original X, so Y is unchanged

this isn't exactly true, but its close enough to understand the principle

Comment: Given the way `np.ndarray` objects work, "X[0] = 2 makes x[0] point to 2" is simply wrong, but won't downvote because of that last disclaimer.

Answer (score 3):

This is more about convention and names than reference and value.

When you assign:

```
Y = X
```

Then the name `Y` refers to the object that the name `X` points to. In some way the pointer `X` and `Y` point to the same object:

```
X is Y   # True
```

The `is` checks if the names point to the same object!

---

Then it get's tricky: You do some operations on the arrays.

```
X[0] = 2
```

That's called "item assignment" and calls

```
X.__setitem__(0, 2)
```

What `__setitem__` should do (convention) is to update some value in the container `X`. So `X` should still point to the same object afterwards.

However `X * 2` is "multiplication" and the convention states that this should create a new object (again convention, you can change that behaviour by overwriting `X.__mul__`). So when you do

```
X = X * 2
```

The name `X` now refers to the new object that `X * 2` created:

```
X is Y   # False
```

Normally common libraries follow these conventions but it's important to highlight that you can completly change this!

Comment: I'd say it's more a question of implementation than convention. While convention may dictate one thing or the other, the implementation of numpy arrays is what defines the behavior of the operators in the end. In this case of course implementation follows convention.

Comment: Also, technically OP asked about `2 * X`, so `__rmul__`, but again, for numpy it's commutative.

Comment: I modified my question title based on your suggestion. It's hard to even ask questions for beginner. Thanks!

Comment: @SunnyYang I actually think the original title was appropriate as well. It's just that Python follows the "consenting adults" guidelines. That makes it very hard to answer such questions generally, because as MadPhysicist pointed out that depends on the actual implementation, which in my opinion should follow the Python conventions. However in specific cases (and you used a numpy array as example) it's easy to answer because NumPy follows (most) python conventions.

Comment: @MadPhysicist You're right. But I think it's easier to explain the conventions than to discuss possible implementations. The conventions for these operations are pretty explicit in Pythons data model. However there are lots of implementations that can break these conventions (for example `return self` in `__mul__`). And yes, I cheated a bit with `__mul__` but to explain how `__mul__` and `__rmul__` work with Python & NumPy would make an answer on itself, especially if subclasses and `__array_priority__` is involved.

Answer (score 2):

When you say `X = np.array([1, 0, 0])`, you create an object that has some methods and some internal buffers that contain the actual data and other information in it.

Doing `Y = X` sets `Y` to refer to the same actual object. This is called binding to a name in Python. You have bound the same object that was bound to `X` to the name `Y` as well.

Doing `X[0] = 2` calls the object's `__setitem__` method, which does some stuff to the underlying buffers. If modifies the object in place. Now when you print the values of either `X` or `Y`, the numbers that come out of that object's buffers are `2, 0, 0`.

Doing `X = 2 * X` translates to `X.__rmul__(2)`. This method does not modify `X` in place. It creates and returns a new array object, each of whose elements is twice the corresponding element of `X`. Then you bind the new object to the name `X`. However, the name `Y` is still bound to the original array because you have not done anything to change that. As an aside, `X.__rmul__` is used because `2.__mul__(X)` does not work. Numpy arrays naturally define multiplication to be commutative, so `X.__mul__` and `X.__rmul__` should to the same thing.

It is interesting to note that you can also do `X *= 2`, which will propagate the changes to `Y`. This is because the `*=` operator translates to the `__imul__` method, which *does* modify the input in place.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the X*=2. I have to keep it in mind or!